# Best Practices: Scheduled Reports

Tags: bestpractice, scheduled

We are having issues with tons of different users trying to schedule reports, and it is causing others to not be able to schedule their reports because only 2 reports can be scheduled in 1 hour.

I am trying to put some best practices together for this, so we don't run into this issue anymore.

I was wondering if anybody out there already has some best practices for this, so I can get an idea of what all to put in ours?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Limit the number of people who can schedule? And with the new Analytics API maybe you can invoke them remotely?

Comment: Building on Mike's idea, you could centralize the scheduling, having people submit requests for scheduled reports rather than scheduling themselves. That way a central person can schedule them to be delivered, can consolidate requests so that a single request sends the same scheduled report to multiple users, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I see two options

1) Upgrade your Salesforce edition, see [Analytics Limits Per Edition](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_analytics_per_edition.htm&language=en_US)

2) Try [Conga Courier](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016ZopEAE) apps from AppExchange marketplace

Comment: Since Unlimited and Performance are the Editions which allow the two-per-hour max that Adam says he's up against, upgrading won't help.